# Teknonymy in English:referring to someone by the name of their child

Tags: single-word-requests, history

In Arabic , we have a way to call people using using their child name or even a name they chose. The name will be as follows :

(Abu)+ name of child
Abu means father of

(Um)+ name of child
Um means mother of

Is there a similar way to call people in English?

Comment: Hello, Rani2Add. Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. In any case, basic research is required to be shown. For instance, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teknonymy) mentions teknonymy in quite a few languages, but fails to mention English.

Comment: Wikipedia articles may sometimes be incomplete. Asking here may add some useful information to my knowledge

Comment: Questions not including reasonable research on ELU _are always_ incomplete. / If you did not know the term 'teknonymy', 'reasonable research' would be assessed very differently. / You could also try the [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-tek1.htm) article, which appears near the top of Google hits for the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say, for example, 'Dylan's mum' or 'Jessica's dad' to describe someone. You wouldn't normally address them that way. Sometimes children might address their friends' parents that way, when they don't know better.